# How to set ranger as default file manager

Tags: shell, sed, syntax, file-manager, r-ranger

Related: [Here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=65125#p65125), [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ranger/comments/rbjd8t/), [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680602/ranger-file-manager-as-default-file-), & [Here](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/2517).

I want to be able to use gui applications with ranger, e.g., I want to click a desktop folder icon & have it open in ranger.

Steps I take & errors that follow:

1. Set `/home/ertecturing/.scripts/Ranger_Default_File_Manager.sh "%s"` as default file manager in xfce settings
2. Ranger_Default_File_Manager.sh runs
   `xfce4-terminal -T "Ranger File Manager" -x ranger $@`
   This commands almost works, but it creates a directory error because directories given by $@ always start with only file:/// not file://// like they need to in order to function.
3. I tried to add the missing 4th slash with this sed command someone shared with me:
   `OUT=$(sed -e 's/\/\/\//\/\/\/\//g' $1)`
   `xfce4-terminal -T "Ranger File Manager" -x ranger $OUT`
   I have little idea whether that first line's syntax is correct.
   The first line only produces blank output, but if I test a similar command `echo $@ | sed "s/\/\/\//\/\/\/\//g" >> ~/Desktop/file` it always outputs the 4th slash I'm looking for.

Does anyone know a way to solve this issue? Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your `OUT` variable to the command that you say works may be a better approach.

```
OUT=$(echo "$@" | sed 's|$|/|g')
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional Solution for Spaces:

1. `OUT=$(echo "$@" | sed "s:///:////:g" | sed "s/%20/ /g")`
2. `xfce4-terminal -T "Ranger File Manager" -x ranger "$OUT"`